# How to replace double quotes to single quotes in c# or jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

My string is `<br/>`

```
var lookfor = "\(Dos LIKE ''" + Dos + "'' OR Practice LIKE ''" + PracticeName + "''  OR Patient LIKE ''" + PatientName + "''  OR ClaimId LIKE ''" + ClaimId + "'' OR Charges LIKE ''" + Charges + "'' OR Payment  LIKE ''" + Payment + "'' OR InsuranceStatus  LIKE ''" + Status + "'')";
```

but i required a string `<br/>`

```
var lookfor = '\(Dos LIKE ''" + Dos + "'' OR Practice LIKE ''" + PracticeName + "''  OR Patient LIKE ''" + PatientName + "''  OR ClaimId LIKE ''" + ClaimId + "'' OR Charges LIKE ''" + Charges + "'' OR Payment  LIKE ''" + Payment + "'' OR InsuranceStatus  LIKE ''" + Status + "'')';
```

I am try this code but cannot resolved it

```
var jsonStr = lookfor.replace(/"/g, "'");
var jsonStr1= lookfor.replace(/"/g, '\'');
```

please help....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Do not replace them - use sql parameters.

Comment: "but i required a string <br/>" , what does that mean? Are you looking for values that contain a ´<br/>´ ? Do you think your ´lookfor´ variable needs to have a break in it? ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lookfor = "\\(Dos LIKE ''" + Dos + "'' OR Practice LIKE ''" + PracticeName + "''  OR Patient LIKE ''" + PatientName + "''  OR ClaimId LIKE ''" + ClaimId + "'' OR Charges LIKE ''" + Charges + "'' OR Payment  LIKE ''" + Payment + "'' OR InsuranceStatus  LIKE ''" + Status + "'')";
var newTemp = lookfor.Replace("\"", "'");
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/u4g1Wm)

Answer (score -1):

var jsonStr = lookfor.replace(@"""", @"\""");